# Why constructor return object with the same name as itself

Tags: javascript, constructor, javascript-objects

While creating a new object, why does constructor not return object with the name of the newly created object

In the following, the output is `cons{x: "hi"}` object, why not `myobj {x: "hi"}`?

```js
function cons() {
  this.x = "hi";
  return null;
}

var myobj = new cons();
console.log(myobj);
```

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript), says that *"It returns the newly created object,unless the constructor function returns a non-null object reference."* So it should return `myobj{x: "hi"}` since the above constructor is returning `null`.

Comment: "cons" in the log output is not the name of the *object*, it's the name of the object's constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by the "name" of the object? There's an object that you assign to a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the following, the output is `cons{x: "hi"}` object, why not `myobj {x: "hi"}`?

What you see will vary depending on which console implementation you're using, but some (like Chrome's) will indeed show you that.

The `cons` there is to tell you what *type* of object it is,<sup>1</sup> not what variable the object's reference is stored in. It's just so you can readily distinguish between the different types of objects in your code when looking at the dev tools.

As for why: Remember that `console.log` has no idea where the value it got came from; it doesn't know the value came from a variable called `myobj`. When you do `console.log(myobj)`, the **value** of `myobj` is read, and then that **value** is passed into `console.log`. So it couldn't print the variable name even if the designers of it wanted it to.

If you want to see the variable name as well, put it in the `console.log` call:

```
console.log("myobj", myobj);
```

Example:

```js
function cons() {
  this.x = "hi";
  return null;
}

var myobj = new cons();
console.log("myobj", myobj);
```

---

> This article, says that "It returns the newly created object,unless the constructor function returns a non-`null` object reference." So it should return `myobj{x: "hi"}` since the above constructor is returning null.

You're quite understandably confusing two unrelated things. The result of calling a constructor function with `new`, and the output of passing an object reference into `console.log`.

In your code, `var myobj = new cons();` does indeed result in the new object created by `new` being stored in `myobj` (the `return null;` has no effect on it). What that quote is trying to say is that something like this wouldn't:

```js
function cons() {
  this.x = "hi";
  return {hey: "I'm a completely different object"};
}

var myobj = new cons();
console.log(myobj);
```

In that code, `cons` has *overridden* the default behavior of `new` by returning a non-`null` object reference to something other than `this`. So the result of `new cons` is a reference to that *other* object, not the one `new` created. It's not something constructors usually need to do, but sometimes (for instance) you want something that looks like a constructor to actually provide a previous instance instead of the new object.

---

<sup>1</sup> Loosely speaking; objects don't really have *type* in JavaScript, just a prototypical inheritance lineage.

Answer (score 1):

Objects have no name in general. What you are seeing is an implementation-dependent stringification of the object. Firefox console would show

```
Object { x: "hi" }
```

Chrome presumably shows the name of the constructor of that object. Functions do have a name.